# Why order of variables inside each statement affects output?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

In rails, what difference does it make when I switch the order of two variables in an `each` statement:

```
flash.each do |name, msg|
  content_tag :div, msg, class: "alert alert-info"
#output => "Successfully updated item"
```

Comparing with:

```
flash.each do |msg, name|
  content_tag :div, msg, class: "alert alert-info"
#output => notice
```

Of course in my `item_controller` I have this:

```
def update
  if @item.update(item_params)
    redirect_to @item, notice: "Successfully updated items"
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, `flash` is a hash http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Hash.html which means there are `keys` and `values` stored like a dictionary. It is a bit different that a regular variable you are probably used to working with. To help you get the concept, you can think of the keys inside of the hash as sub-variables. When you iterate through a hash using something like `.each`, you will always get the key first then the value, the key will never be `nil` but the value might.

**Example**

```
def update
  if @item.update(item_params)
    # This line is saying redirect and add a key, value to the
    # flash hash, with the key being 'notice' and the 'value'
    # "Successfully updated items"
    redirect_to @item, notice: "Successfully updated items"
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

You asked a question above of if you only have one variable would it be a key or value. It wouldn't be either it would just be a variable.

**Example**

```
str = 'Hello'
content_tag :div, str, class: "alert alert-info"
#output => "Hello"
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you're trying to get info from the flash var who's defined like this:

```
flash = {
  notice: "Successfully updated items"
}
```

Each statement, uses the key, value pair for fetching and manipulating the hash.

```
flash.each do |key, value|
  #doSomething
end
```

In this case, the key is "notice" and the value "Successfully updated items".

Comment: So if I only have one variable, would it be key or value?

Comment: @rex if only one block variable is given then it will be assigned an array whose first element is a key,  and the second element is the value.